# chamar uma variável designada localmente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso chamar uma variavel que é vazia, porém como fazer?
Criei o seguinte código

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     cliente cliente;
            try
            {
                 cliente = db.cliente.find(id);
                //etc
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var GravaLogErro = new ErroDotNet
                {

                    IDC = cliente != null ? cliente.ClienteId : 0
[Ele fala: User of unasigned local variable 'cliente']
                };
                GravaLogErro.GravarLog();

            }
```

Não queria colocar o cliente.find fora do try/catch até pq eu resumi bem a lógica, porque não posso fazer uma verificação se é null?
O Certo seria eu criar ela assim?

```
cliente cliente = new cliente();
```

Não daria depois problema no find()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode alocar nulo também. A vantagem é que o código fica mais previsível.

```
cliente cliente = null;
```

Só que não parece ter muita vantagem no *catch* você tentar acessar o cliente, porque se você entrou ali, é porque o find falhou e você não tem o cliente correto, acho melhor você imprimir o id com o qual você tentou achar o cliente...